# If $X$ is a r.v. is there an independent r.v. $Y$ on the same space?

Tags: probability

Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space and $X,Y$ two random variable with distribution $F_X$ and $F_Y$. I know how to construct a probability space $(\Omega ',\mathcal F',\mathbb P')$ s.t. $X$ and $Y$ are independents. But, I was wondering if there exist a r.v. $Z$ on $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ with distribution $F_Y$ s.t. $X$ and $Z$ are independents, or we cannot answer this question in general ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in general there doesn't exist such a random variable $Z$.

Consider for instance $$\Omega= \{0,1\}, \qquad \mathcal{F}=\{\emptyset,\{0\},\{1\},\Omega\}$$ endowed with the measure $$\mathbb{P}(\{0\}) = \frac{1}{2} = \mathbb{P}(\{1\}).$$ If we define $$X(\omega) := Y(\omega):=\begin{cases} 1, & \omega = 0, \\ -1, & \omega=1 \end{cases}$$ then $X$ and $Y$ have distribution $$F = \frac{1}{2} \delta_{-1} + \frac{1}{2} \delta_1.$$ However, there doesn't exist a random variable $Z$ which is independent of $X$ and which has distribution $F$. Why? The only random variables on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ with distribution $F$ are the random variables $$X = 1_{\{0\}} - 1_{\{1\}} \qquad \text{and} -X = -1_{\{0\}} + 1_{\{1\}}.$$ Since $X$ is not independent from itself and $X$ is not independent from $-X$, this means that we cannot find a random variable $Z$ with the desired properties.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I know that $((0,1),\mathcal B(0,1), m)$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure has all random variable from any distribution. Do you think that the statement would be true on this space ?

Comment: When you say : $X$ and $Y$ has distribution $F=\frac{1}{2}\delta _{-1}+\frac{1}{2}\delta _1$, I guess that you mean "density function" (where $\delta _i$ is the Dirac mass). Otherwise it would be strange since $\delta _i$ are not functions...

Comment: @user659895 Re your 2nd comment: It is exactly the other way round. I'm talking about the distribution and not about the density function. The dirac mass is a measure (not a function) and hence $F$ is a measure (and not a function). By "distribution" of a random variable $X$ on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ I mean the measure $F(B) := \mathbb{P}(X \in B)$.

Comment: @user659895 Re your first comment: I'm not sure whether it's true for this particular probability space. In any case, you can find indepdent random variables $U$ and $V$ such that $U$ has the same distribution as $X$ and $V$ has the same distribution as $Y$. I will think about it

Comment: Many thanks for your last contribution, that's very interesting to know :) (is it difficult to prove ?)

Comment: @user659895 Not very difficult, no. The first observation is that it suffices to show that there exist independent random variables $G$ and $H$ on $\Omega=(0,1)$ (endowed with Lebesgue measure) such that $G$ and $G$ are uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$. If we can find such random variables, then $U :=F_X^{-1}(G)$ and $V:= F_Y^{-1}(H)$ are independent random variables on $\Omega$, $U$ has distribution $F_X$ and $V$ has distribution $F_Y$. (Here $F_X^{-1}$ denotes the generalized inverse of $F_X$.) The existence of $G$ and $H$ is not that difficult to show, e.g. via dyadic numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The set $\Omega$ might be too small to support two nontrivial independent random variables with specified distribution.  Such as, if $\Omega$ has two elements, and $P(X=0)=P(Y=0)=2/3$ and $P(X=1)=P(Y=1)=1/3$, there is no $Z$ independent of $X$ with the distribution of $Y$, and so on.  Slightly more abstractly, if the field generated by $X$ is the same as $\mathcal F$, there can be no nontrivial $Y$ independent of $X$.